# How to divide array into groups by an item in it in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say I have an array:

```
array = [{"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"1"},
{"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"2"},
{"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"3"},
{"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"2"},
{"account_id"=>"10", "ad"=>"3"},
{"account_id"=>"04", "ad"=>"4"}]
```

How can I divide it into groups divided by account_id like

```
l1 = [{"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"1"},{"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"2"}]
l2 = [{"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"2"},{"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"3"}]
....
```

and then return the lists together.

How can I do this? Is there any exist APIs? Furthermore, I'm thinking of using data structure like a list of lists (like `List<List<Map<String, String>>>` in Java? Sorry I'm new to Ruby), but let me know if there's better way to present. Thanks

Comment: Try this: `array.group_by { |h| h["account_id"] }.transform_keys.with_index(1) { |k,i| ? }`. See [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Hash#transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) (new in Ruby v2.5) and [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index).

Comment: If `l1` and `l2` are meant to be local variables that cannot be done. Since Ruby v1.8 it has not been possible to create locally variables dynamically. My previous comment assumed you meant them to be keys of a hash that are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = [{"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"1"},
         {"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"2"},
         {"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"3"},
         {"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"2"},
         {"account_id"=>"10", "ad"=>"3"},
         {"account_id"=>"04", "ad"=>"4"}]


p array.group_by { |h| h['account_id']}
```

REsult

```
{"01"=>[{"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"1"}, {"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"2"}], "05"=>[{"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"2"}, {"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"3"}], "10"=>[{"account_id"=>"10", "ad"=>"3"}], "04"=>[{"account_id"=>"04", "ad"=>"4"}]}
```

Or you may the result as follows

```
array.group_by { |h| h['account_id']}.values.each do |value|
  p value
end
```

Result

```
[{"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"1"}, {"account_id"=>"01", "ad"=>"2"}]
[{"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"2"}, {"account_id"=>"05", "ad"=>"3"}]
[{"account_id"=>"10", "ad"=>"3"}]
[{"account_id"=>"04", "ad"=>"4"}]
```